# Flutter: Sign In With Facebook Android Package Visibility

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, facebook

I have implemented Sign in with Facebook following the instructions [here][1]. However, I keep getting the following error when I run the function on an Android Emulator:

```
W/com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol(21322): Apps that target Android API 30+ (Android 11+) cannot call Facebook native apps unless the package visibility needs are declared. Please follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting/#faq_267321845055988 to make the declaration.
W/com.facebook.internal.NativeProtocol(21322): Apps that target Android API 30+ (Android 11+) cannot call Facebook native apps unless the package visibility needs are declared. Please follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/troubleshooting/#faq_267321845055988 to make the declaration.
```

When you read how to fix the visibility, you simply add the providers to the queries in Manifest file, which I have, but it still is not working and I keep getting this error.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fytfeed.fytfeed"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
<queries>
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" /> <!-- allows app to access Facebook app features -->
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.orca.provider.PlatformProvider" /> <!-- allows sharing to Messenger app -->
  </intent>
</queries>

</manifest>
```

Any idea why this error continues to show?

EDIT:
The default config is set as follows

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fytfeed.fytfeed"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

UPDATE 2:
I added the strings for the Facebook appID and client token, and now I am getting a new error

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="appID"/>
       <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
           android:value="clientToken"/>
```

New error is

```
I/flutter (26846): On pressed error:
I/flutter (26846): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method login on channel app.meedu/flutter_facebook_auth)
```

Also, I am using an emulator, would that have anything to do with it?
[1]: https://facebook.meedu.app/docs/5.x.x/android

Comment: hey, is your target SDK version to 30 or higher in defaultConfig?

Comment: @AmiraliEricJanani I believe so. I just updated my question to show you how I have the defaultConfig setup. Do I need to change any of this?

Comment: Make sure to replace "@string/facebook_app_id" with the actual value of your Facebook app ID.     <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

Comment: @AmiraliEricJanani I did not have that set properly, so thank you! However, now I am getting a new error (see above in my second update).

Comment: Have you test it on real device?

Comment: @AmiraliEricJanani I have not in debug mode, but I have had a release build to testers where the FB login still isn't working and showing an error when it tries to open the Facebook app.